# Why would the Restore History table not be populated per database restore?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My [msdb].[dbo].[restorehistory] table on my server is empty but I have performed numerous restores in the past from production bak files to my development server.

Should I be looking for a maintenance job that truncates this table or is there a setting that keeps the table from being populated?

If there is a maintenance job that runs sp_delete_backuphistory - what's the best way to track it down?

Its a sql 2012 server with simple recovery mode and change tracking set to false.

I'm querying for data with this script:

```
WITH LastRestores AS
(
SELECT
    DatabaseName = [d].[name] ,
    [d].[create_date] ,
    [d].[compatibility_level] ,
    [d].[collation_name] ,
    r.[restore_date],
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.Name ORDER BY r.[restore_date] DESC)
FROM master.sys.databases d
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.[restorehistory] r ON r.[destination_database_name] = d.Name
)
SELECT *
FROM [LastRestores]
WHERE [RowNum] = 1
```

My restore date is null and this shows that the table is empty

```
select top 1 * from msdb.dbo.[restorehistory]
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer so I want to close this question.

I found a maintenance job that is running the sp_delete_backuphistory store procedure on a daily basis through a sql agent job.  So the table is getting populated but then gets deleted nightly.